# Website refuses to open on custom domain but works on IP

Tags: django, apache, nginx, dns, hosting

I am trying to bring my Django website online with a custom domain.

The website is [melius.live](http://melius.live) and the IP of the webserver is [157.90.29.120](http://157.90.29.120). However, opening the IP works fine, opening the domain usually doesn't work, sometimes it gives me an Apache default page (I am using NGINX, not Apache), but normally just a connection refused.

The site is written in Django, I am using Hetzner for hosting and Namecheap for the domain.

When I do a traceroute, the correct IP shows up.

Where is the problem?

Comment: For me both URLs look the same…

Comment: What the hell? I kept refreshing the site with no luck... Thanks I suppose...

Comment: It looks like some browser cache issue. If you use Chrome open developer tools, check "Disable cache" in Network tab and refresh again.

Comment: And when in doubt better use `curl` 